# Exporting empty csv in SSRS from data driven subscription

Tags: csv, reporting-services, export

How do I remove the commas from an exported csv file created from an SSRS (2012) data driven subscription when the data returned is empty? The report is created daily then exported as a csv file. When the report returns no results the csv file exported consists of one line of commas only. When it does return results it outputs a proper csv file.  The file needs to be generated daily regardless of the results but needs to be empty without the commas when no data is returned?

e.g. when data is returned:

Name1, Address1, City1, State1, Zip1

Name2, Address2, City2, State2, Zip2

e.g. when data is not returned I need it to be blank but it currently creates:

,,,,

Comment: Id love an answer to this question